# Default Values on DetailsView Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-membership

When users go to a specified page, I have a DetailsView attached to a SqlDataSource and already setup in Insert mode.  I'm essentially using it as a registration page for certain events.  Rather than having the users type in their "UserName", I want that field to automatically populate based on that user already being logged in.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to either have the User.Identity.Name be the default value that appears on Page_load, or how to code an override on DetailsViewInsertEventArgs?  Of course, if I'm totally off-base, then other suggestions would be great.

I'm using c# code behind.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Some code would help us understand your question a little better.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DetailsView1.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
            if (DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1") != null)
            {
                TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1");
                txt1.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get this to work, I had to put the code inside a OnDataBound event handler, instead of Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Thanks Ricardo.  That makes sense, but I'm still having trouble getting it to work.  I guess I forgot to mention that the control is in a boundfield, if that makes a difference.

Here's the mainpage code:

```
<div align="center">
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataKeyNames="RegistrationID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceFBReg" 
        DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" 
        Width="55%" OnItemInserted="NFLElim" >
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RegistrationID" HeaderText="RegistrationID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RegistrationID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="One Season User Name" 
                SortExpression="UserName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />...
```

And here's how I have the code behind setup:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class NFLElim_Reg : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DetailsView1.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
            if (DetailsView1.FindControl("UserName") != null)
            {
                TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("UserName");
                txt1.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
    protected void NFLElim(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Account.aspx");
    }

}
```

Hopefully I inserted the code correctly

Comment: That should do it, you inserted the code correctly. This should work even in a bound field.

Comment: This doesn't work.  FindControl only works on TextBox fields inside a TemplateField

Answer (score 0):

TextBox tata = (TextBox)DetailsView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Controls[0];
tata.Text=User.Identity.Name;

This will chane boundfield. If you change your boundfield to templatefield, this code can also work:

TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("UserName");
txt1.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how you want to do it, but if you want to use Session, it is a really easy fix. I was actually just researching this myself.

If you store your username in Session, you can pull it right from there as a parameter into your SQLDataSource.

All I did was add a SessionParameter to my InsertParameter list in markup view.

In your case, I would recommend going to the markup for the SqlDataSourceFBReg control, and looking for the list of InsertParameters.

Then, add an asp:SessionParameter with Name="UserName" and SessionField="whatever the session name is"